# Load System.Object into DataGrid

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to fetch some data from SCCM and place this information in a datagrid. The code for my datagrid looks like this:

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window_GuiManagement" Title="SCCM" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen" 
    Width = "587.000" Height = "500.000" Visibility="Visible" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_result" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="11,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="299" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="1">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
"@
```

And the SCCM information I catch like this:

```
$data = Get-CMDevice | Where-Object {
    $_.LastLogonUser -like '*Walker*'
} | Select Name
```

I tried

```
$datagrid_result.ItemsSource = $data
```

The result is a `System.Object`, same as you get when you run eg. `Get-Culture | Select Name` but it results in an error:

> Exception setting "ItemsSource": "Cannot convert the "@{Name=PCName}" value of type 
>   "Selected.Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject" to type "System.Collections.IEnumerable"."

What I wish to have is in the end a list of all computers that a specific user logged on to recently.

Comment: `Select Name` -> `Select -Expand Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Select Name` to `Select -Expand Name` and change the type of `$data` to `[string[]]`:

```
[string[]]$data = Get-CMDevice | Where-Object {
    $_.LastLogonUser -like '*Walker*'
} | Select -Expand Name
```

This way you'll be assigning an array of strings as the `ItemSource` (which it'll accept), rather than a single WQL query result object

Comment: Hi Mathias,
thanks. This already helps :).
Unfortunately, it does not allow too add more columns?!? In case I want to add values like  LastLogonUser, CNLastOnlineTime I have to remove the Expand parameter but then all data will be returned in a single column and not shared into further ones.

I also tried to modify my XAML with the binding but no luck so far:
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [2]}" Header="PC Name"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastLogonUser}" Header="LastLogonUser"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Time"/>

Comment: Additional info, my array looks like this:
@{Name=PCName; LastLogonUser=Walker; CNLastOnlineTime=07/17/2019 12:04:57}

Comment: I think I found the mistake. My variable was somehow broken: $result = Get-CMDevice | Where-Object { $_.LastLogonUser -like '*schneider*' } | Select Name, LastLogonUser, CNLastOnlineTime